# Unpivot SQL OR Cross-Apply table with row data as column headings and row data as column data

Tags: sql, sql-server, transpose, unpivot, cross-apply

I know this question has been asked many time but I have not been able to find a solution with my data structure. I did however come across the following article [An Alternative (Better?) Method to UNPIVOT (SQL Spackle)](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/cross+apply+values+unpivot/91234/).

I have the following table with the raw data result as follows

```
    RowType | LocalDate | UTCDate | Target1 | Target2 | Target3
    KPIName     NULL        NULL     Feed1     Feed2     Feed3
    Balance     NULL        NULL    Product   Reagent    Water
    UoM         NULL        NULL       t        t          %
    ActiveDate 2017-01-01 2016-12-31   5.0     3.2        20
```

The result I am trying to achieve is the following

```
KPIName | Balance | ActiveDate | UTCDate  | UoM | Value
 Feed1    Product   2017-01-01  2016-12-31  t     5.0
 Feed2    Reagent   2017-01-01  2016-12-31  t     3.2
 Feed3    Water     2017-01-01  2016-12-31  %     20
```

Comment: I see  no way to  group rows. What if  one more package of 4 rows is added for the other date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1
    ([RowType] varchar(10), [LocalDate] varchar(10), [UTCDate] varchar(10), [Target1] varchar(7), [Target2] varchar(7), [Target3] varchar(5))
;

INSERT INTO #Table1
    ([RowType], [LocalDate], [UTCDate], [Target1], [Target2], [Target3])
VALUES
    ('KPIName', NULL, NULL, 'Feed1', 'Feed2', 'Feed3'),
    ('Balance', NULL, NULL, 'Product', 'Reagent', 'Water'),
    ('UoM', NULL, NULL, 't', 't', '%'),
    ('ActiveDate', '2017-01-01', '2016-12-31', '5.0', '3.2', '20')
;
 SELECT 
X.KPINAME,X.BALANCE,LOCALDATE,UTCDATE,X.UOM,X.VALUE
FROM #TABLE1
 CROSS APPLY (
    VALUES ('FEED1', 'PRODUCT','T',5.0)
    ,('FEED2', 'REAGENT','T',3.2)
    ,('FEED3', 'WATER','%',20)) X(KPINAME, BALANCE,UOM,VALUE)
    WHERE LOCALDATE IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: The result is correct the problem is that you have specified the cross apply values, my table result 470 rows. Is there no way of achieving without specify the physical values?